# Submitted property won't update after onClick event is fired

Tags: javascript, reactjs, styled-components

I think that my `Styled Component` won't update when the `onClick event` is fired.

Setting the variable statically on true did show what it should have shown.
I tried to `console.log()` the variable what I'm updating and that is doing its  work as I expected.

- passing `collapsedMenuIsActive` to `<StyledNavBarList>`
- `toggleCollapsedMenu` will toggle from `false` to `true` and reversed when the `<StyledNavBarBurger>` is clicked

This is where the the variable will be toggled with the onClick event.

```
let collapsedMenuIsActive = false;

const toggleCollapsedMenu = () => {
    collapsedMenuIsActive = (!collapsedMenuIsActive);
}

{/* I have tried both of these two lines below here */}
{/* <StyledNavBarBurger onClick={toggleCollapsedMenu}> */}
<StyledNavBarBurger onClick={() => toggleCollapsedMenu}>
    ...
</StyledNavBarBurger>
<StyledNavBarList isActive={collapsedMenuIsActive}>
    ...
</StyledNavBarList>
```

This is my styled component.

```
export const StyledNavBarList = styled.ul`
    ...

    ${MEDIA.smallPhone`
        display: ${props => props.isActive ? 'block' : 'none'};
        ...
    `}
`;
```

I expect when the onClick event will be fired that the variable that i'm updating will update the the `props.isActive` value inside my `styled component`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to trigger React to re-render based on a variable, you should be using `setState` and storing your `collapsedMenuIsActive` in your state object. Something like the following should work, but note without your full code, it may not be exact:

```
export default class extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            collapsedMenuIsActive: false
        };
    }

    toggleCollapsedMenu = () => {
        // This will update the state in your state object
        // and instruct React to re-render this component with the new state.
        // It's important that you use the function form of setState when
        // changing the state based on current/previous state values.
        this.setState(state => ({
            collapsedMenuIsActive: !state.collapsedMenuIsActive
        }));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <StyledNavBarBurger onClick={this.toggleCollapsedMenu}>
                    ...
                </StyledNavBarBurger>
                <StyledNavBarList isActive={this.state.collapsedMenuIsActive}>
                    ...
                </StyledNavBarList>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

To learn more about React state, read the [official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html). Note that the `React.Fragment` is not necessary with the state, it's being used here to simply wrap two components in the render to help with this specific example. It could also simply be a `div` or wrapped by some other node/element.

Answer (score 0):

You should use state for that:

```
class Menu extends Component {
  state = {
    collapsedMenuIsActive: false,
  };

  toggleCollapsedMenu = () => {
    const status = this.state.collapsedMenuIsActive;
    this.setState({ collapsedMenuIsActive: !status });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        <button onClick={this.toggleCollapsedMenu}> Click me to change state</button>
        {this.state.collapsedMenuIsActive ? 'is active' : 'is not active'}
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

If you now pass `this.state.collapsedMenuIsActive` to your StyledNavBarList component, it should do what was desired.